# При вызове метода ничего не происходит.С++

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;
#define  N 5

class Man {
    string name;
    int age;
    string city;
public:
    virtual void about() {
        printf("Hi, my name's %s.I'm %i.I live in %s.", name.c_str(), age, city.c_str());
    }

    virtual void fiiling() {
        cout << "Enter your name: ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter your age: ";
        cin >> age;
        cout << "Enter  city of residence:";
        cin >> city;

    }


};

class Student : public Man {

protected:
    char status;
    char statusStudy;
    char statusAvarang;
    string university;  // университет
    string faculty; // факультет
    string group;   // Группа
    int course;    //курс
    float evaluation[N];
    float avarangPoint;
    bool isStudy;


public:

    void about() override {
        Man::about();
        printf("I study in %s.faculty %s,group %s, course %s.", university.c_str(), faculty.c_str(), group.c_str(),
               course);

    }

    void fiiling() override {
        Man::fiiling();
        cout << "Enter your university: ";
        cin >> university;
        cout << "Enter faculty: ";
        cin >> faculty;
        cout << "Enter group:";
        cin >> group;
        cout << "Enter course: ";
        cin >> course;
        cout << "Do you study now? Y/N ";
        cin >> statusStudy;
        if (statusStudy == 'Y' || statusStudy == 'y') {
            isStudy = true;
        } else isStudy = false;

        cout << "Want to specify your ratings? Y/N ";
        cin >> status;
        if (status == 'Y' || status == 'y') {
            fiillPoint();
        }

    }

    void fiillPoint() {  // заполнение оценок
        for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
            cout << "Enter your point in subject " << i + 1 << endl;
            cin >> evaluation[i];
        }
        cout << " Want to know the average ball? Y/N ";
        cin >> statusAvarang;
        if (statusStudy == 'Y' || statusStudy == 'y') {
            avarangPoint = gradePointAverage();
            cout << "Your avarenge point: " << avarangPoint << endl;
        } else cout << "GoodBye " << endl;;
    }

    float gradePointAverage() {      // средний  балл
        float temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            temp += evaluation[i];
        }
        return temp / N;
    }

    void state() {
        if (isStudy) { cout << "I am study now " << endl; }
        else { cout << "I'm don't study now :D" << endl; }

    }

};

class Sportsman : public Student {
    char status;
protected:
    string kindOfSport;
    int yearsOfSports;

public:
    void about() override {
        Student::about();
        printf("In my free time I play %s.I've been doing it for %i years already", kindOfSport.c_str(), yearsOfSports);
    }

    void fiiling() override {
        Student::fiiling();
        cout << "What sports do you do ? ";
        cin >> kindOfSport;
        cout << "How many years have you been doing it? ";
        cin >> yearsOfSports;

        cout << "do you want to train? Y/N";
        cin >> status;
        if (status == 'Y' || status == 'y') {
            training();
        } else { cout << "GoodBye " << endl; }


    }


    void training() {   // тренировка

        cout << "going to the gym......" << endl;
        cout << "I train..." << endl;
    }


};

int main() {
//
//    cout << "=======================Student================"<<endl;
//    Student student;
//    student.fiiling();
//    student.about();

    cout << endl << "=======================Sportsman================" << endl;
    Sportsman sportsman;
    sportsman.fiiling();
    sportsman.about();`введите сюда код`
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

При вызове метода about(); на любом обьекте ничего не происходит только завершаеться программа. Хотя метод fiiling(); работает корректно. В чём беда ?

Comment: Вам стоит научится пользоваться дебаггером.  С его помощью можно будет выполнить программу строчка за строчкой и локализовать проблему. Ну а вообще стоит компилировать с включенными предупреждениями. В данном случае компилятор бы четко указал на ошибку.

Comment: В 49 строке вместо 4-ого `%s` должен быть `%d`. Если бы вы включите предупреждения компилятора, то он станет показывать на такие ошибки. (Как минимум это относится к GCC.) И вообще, в C++ лучше использовать `cout`...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  я просто в Cline пишу тут ничего не показывает подобного.Спасибо что заметили мой косяк :)

Comment: Clion - это IDE, а не компилятор. Она может использовать разные компиляторы, в том числе и GCC. Не показывает - потому что предупреждения в настройках проекта не включили.

Comment: Но проблему не решило

Comment: Попробуйте добавить перенос строки `\n` в вызовы printf.

Comment: не помогло... :(

Comment: У меня все работает: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6761c16b331bec9e

Comment: Тогда в main - перед `cin.get()` добавить `cout << flush`. Но вообще `\n` должен был сработать. Можно посмотреть новый код со всеми изменениями?

Comment: Cкопирывал Ваш код , ничего не произошло.....

Comment: Потому что в моем коде нет ни `\n`, ни `flush`. Я имею в виду, что у меня и без них все нормально. Еще раз, добавьте `\n` в конец всех строк, которые выводите printf-ом. Если не помогает, добавьте `cout << flush;` перед первым `cin.get();` в `main`. Если и это не помогает, скиньте сюда код со всеми этими изменениями.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, ваша мешанина из функций ввода-вывода их разных стандартных библиотек - С и С++ - вызывает недоумение.

Во-вторых, чтобы на построчно-буферизованных устройствах начало что-то "происходить", необходимо после ваших данных хотя бы вывести символ перевода строки.